# html and javascript validate password in text box

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying to make a website were people enter a code and they get redirected to a page.

Its important that each code takes the user to a diffrent page
for exsample code 123 takes you to index.html and code 000 takes the user to login.html

this is what i have so far but its not working... What am I doing wrong?

index.html:

```
<form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<label>Code :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="button" value="Login" id="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
```

login.js

```
function validate(){

var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
 if ( password == "1234" or "0000" or "4444" ){
alert ("Login successfully");
I dont know what to do now or is this script is even correct.
```

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire. [Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```js
document.getElementById("login").addEventListener("click",function(evt){
    var codeEntered = document.getElementById("password").value.trim();
    // For each different code, use location.href to redirect the user
    switch (codeEntered) {
        case "000":
            location.href = "index.html";
            break;
        case "123":
            location.href = "login.html";
            break;
        default:
            alert("Bad code");
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
<label>Code :</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<button type="button" id="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

Some notes:

- This doesn't really require a form because the button click event handler will initiate the next action
- Don't use **input**s for **buttons**, it is not semantically correct
- Don't use slashes on tags that don't have a closing tag
- Avoid the **onclick** attribute, it is better to use JavaScript to attach events to elements
- Anyone can read the JavaScript and bypass it to go to the page they want to, without entering the code

If you would like to use PHP to handle the code, you should change your HTML like so:

```
<form method="post" action="auth.php">
<label>Code :</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

You should remove all the JavaScript related to the login codes if you are going to use PHP.  Also notice that all the **id** attributes were removed from the HTML because you don't need them if you aren't using JavaScript on those elements.  The **id**s aren't sent to the server, only the **name**s are.  The **button** type changed to *submit* as well.

In **auth.php**, the code would be:

```
<?php
$code = $_POST['code'];
// For each different code, use header("Location: ...") to redirect the user
switch ($code) {
    case "000":
        header("Location: index.html");
        break;
    case "123":
        header("Location: login.html");
        break;
    default:
        echo "Bad code";
}
```

Using PHP protects the codes, people cannot easily access the PHP code.

If you are creating a login system, you will need to remember who has logged in so you can restrict access to pages.  The most common approach is to use a **session** variable.

To add code which sets a session variable to **auth.php** ...

```
<?php
session_start();
$code = trim($_POST['code']);
// For each different code, use header("Location: ...") to redirect the user
switch ($code) {
    case "000": 
        $_SESSION['code'] = $code;       
        header("Location: index.php");
        break;
    case "123":
        $_SESSION['code'] = $code;
        header("Location: login.php");
        break;
    default:
        echo "Bad code";
}
```

In **index.php** and **login.php**, you would reference the session variable like so:

```
<?php
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['code'] === '000') {
    // Do stuff
} else {
    // Force the user to login again
}
```

Be sure to use the **.php** extension to have PHP run the file.

Choose the file names carefully.  **index.php** is usually the first page a site visitor encounters.  If authentication is required, the page is often named **login.php**.  For your code, **index.php** would probably provide a link to **login.php** and then it could run differently after the user has logged in.  In the code in this answer, **auth.php** is determining whether the code is acceptable, then routing the user to the proper page.

Answer (score 0):

What's actually happening is, the default on click action of a submit button in the form is taking you to the redirect URL i.e. this page itself as you haven't mentioned the action attribute.

To do this you'll have to return false from your validate function when you don't want the user to log in.

Returning false from the on-click function will ensure that the default click action handling is not carried out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to accomplish this, just remove onclick="validation()"

login.js

```
    $(function () {

    $('body').on('click', '#submit', function () {
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if (password == "1234" || password == "0000" || password == "4444") {
            alert("Login successfully");
        }

    })
})
```

Or

```
    function validate() {

    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    console.log(password);
    if (password == "1234" ||
        password == "0000"  ||
        password == "4444"
    ) {
        alert("Login successfully");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check this out on JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/61pL5bLf/13/

Comment: But how do I make it so each code goes to a diffrent page?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a php solution is what you're after:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if ($_POST['password'] == '000') {
        header('Location: ' . 'login.html');
        exit;
    }
    if ($_POST['password'] == '123') {
        header('Location: ' . 'index.html');
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```